# how do I copy over a few folders from one directory into another folder in Linux using python

Tags: python, linux, file, io

I'm trying to copy over a bunch of folders, read from a txt file into another folder . How do I do this? I'm using python in Linux

e.g this txt file has the following folder names

```
001YG  
00HFP  
00MFE  
00N38  
00NN7  
00SL4  
00T1E  
00T4B  
00X3U  
00YZL  
00ZCA  
01K8X  
01KM1  
01KML  
01O27  
01THT  
01ZWG
```

and I want to copy these folders and their contents to a folder called `duplicate-folder`

How do I do this? I tried the following code but it gave an error because I think it's only for files, not folders :)

```
with open("missing-list-files.txt",'w') as outfile:
    # outfile.write('\n'.join(temp3))
    for x in temp3:
        outfile.write(x + '\n')

    filelistset = temp3     
    dest = 'mydirectoryhere'
    for file in filelistset:
        shutil.copyfile(file ,dest + file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `shutil.copytree(src, dest, ...)` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) for directories (also copies subfiles and -directories. And also don't forget to give it the full path for file and dest (don't know which value your temp3 var holds). If  you don't give it a full path, but only a filename, it will search in the current working directory.